# mysql server <30% usage, but only 1 large insert per second possible

Tags: mysql, scale, bulkinsert

I have a node API that accepts arrays of up to 1000 email addresses:
These are then sent to the server in a single INSERT INTO statement.
i.e. 1000 ROWS with about 8 columns each.

The API can currently only handle 1 of those requests per second.
I have tried to scale my node server (up and out).
I have also tried to scale up my DB.

Nothing seems to increase the API beyond 1 req/sec

The strange thing is that the API server and DB server usage stay well below 50%.

Is there some other possible bottleneck that might impact the performance?

The code part that takes most of the time is definitely the INSERT INTO statement, but why does it still remain that slow when I scale the DB. And why is the usage % so low?

Comment: The bottleneck might be on disk. You should search for the storage i/o stats

Comment: Show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE  table` output and a example part of the query which you try to execute.. It's wierd because a multi insert should handle alot more in 1 second.. I assume you not running your own server because you talk about scaling i think you could contact your hosting provider with this because this not seams to be normal MySQL performance to me..

Comment: You can try `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` - perhaps there is some unexpected locking

Comment: Triggers, unique keys and foreign keys may also slow down insert operations.